# Replace the below if, else-if, else in shorter way

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I would to replace the below `if, else-if, else`  in shorter way in javascript. How can I do that with ternary operator or filter ? Could someone please advise ? I have added the below ternary but don't know how to include the else condition ?

```
Then('I type {string} in {string} field', (textval, textboxname) => {
    if (textboxname == "Trade Price") {
      cy.get('#DetailsContainer .allowDigits.tradePrice-js').clear().type(parseInt(textval));
    } else if (textboxname == "Email" || textboxname == "Work Phone" || textboxname == "Mobile Phone"|| textboxname == "Home Phone") {
      cy.get('#content_container').parent().find('.fieldHeader').contains(textboxname)
        .next().find('input')
        .type(textval, { force: true })
    } else {
      cy.get('#content_container').parent().find('.fieldHeader').contains(textboxname)
        .next()
        .type(textval, { force: true })
    }
});
```

//Ternary operator

```
function example(…) {
    return textboxname ? "Trade Price"
         : textboxname ? "Mobile"
         : textboxname ? "Work Phone"
         : textboxname? "Home Phone"
         : value4;
}
```

Comment: Is your `else` code the same as your `else if` code? Do they need to be distinguished?

Comment: In your ternary operator the last statement is your final else

Comment: @Ry- I have added `.find('input')` in `else if` condition which is different from else..Sorry  I missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to be using ternary operator the right way. In order to refactor your first snippet of code into a ternary operator, you would do it like this:

```
return (textboxname === "Trade Price" ? {...code to be executed for condition}
         : (textboxname == "Email" || textboxname == "Work Phone"
         || textboxname == "Mobile Phone"|| textboxname == "Home Phone") 
         ? {...code to be executed for condition} 
         : {..final else condition}
       );
```

**BUT**, in use cases like these, it is much cleaner and preferable to use `switch-case`, as you are only concerned with the value of one variable and need to perform operations accordingly:

```
switch(textboxname) {
 case "Trade Price":
        cy.get('#DetailsContainer .allowDigits.tradePrice-js').clear().type(parseInt(textval));
        break;
 
//perform same code for these 4 cases
 case "Email":
 case "Work Phone":
 case "Mobile Phone":
 case "Home Phone":
        cy.get('#content_container').parent().find('.fieldHeader').contains(textboxname)
        .next().find('input')
        .type(textval, { force: true });
        break;

//final else condition
 default:
        cy.get('#content_container').parent().find('.fieldHeader').contains(textboxname)
        .next()
        .type(textval, { force: true });

}
```

Much cleaner than writing ternary operators for these kind of things, as you can see why.

Comment: I will give a try and let you know shortly.

Comment: Fantastic great way to use switch